# How to create low poly Map Terrain on Unreal Engine 5

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, 3dsmax, unreal-engine5

I always stumble over the issue of keeping the polygons of a 3D mesh low, while holding the quality high.
There is a way of forming part of the map in any 3D program and using polygon decreasing mods and integrade them in unreal engine.

But is there any other way? Maybe an integrated function/Plugin of Unreal Engine itself, that will allow to create low poly maps?

Comment: What do you mean by "low poly Map"? Do you mean level geometry, like the terrain? I don't think there is a low poly option for that. For imported meshes, you could use automatic LOD, but low poly modelling is something that should be done beforehand, not automated. Unreal just decimates the mesh without adhering to your artistic decisions, so: No, I don't think there is a viable tool for that.

Also, I believe, this is off-topic for the purpose of SO. Maybe ask in a community about making 3D assets or the unreal forums instead of a programming Q and A site.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply. Secondly, SO is a platform for Q&A and to share technical knowledge. I dont think there is a off-topic Question on SO. This is the opening of SO: "Stack Overflow helps people find the answers they need, when they need them. We're best known for our public Q&A platform that over 100 million people visit every month to ask questions, learn, and share technical knowledge." Alright, so there is no viable tool to decimate the polygons on a mesh with UE5. Thats all i wanted to know, thanks. Regards

Comment: Of course, there are off-topic questions on StackOverflow and I still think that yours can be considered off-topic. Your question is not a programming-problem, about an algorithm, a unique software development problem or about a tool that is used by programmers. No, I do not think 3D software is "programmer software", it's made for artists and the same goes for this aspect of Unreal. See what is considered [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here or ask about it in [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/). Also, asking for a plugin is also considered off-topic.

Comment: Well there are developers working with different toolsets and 3d Software is a technical software. I am a senior C/C++ programmer and yes, there are off-topic things like: Can someone help me with my mowing machine, but alright, dont need to discuss about on and off topics now. Stackoverflow is a knowledge share platform, and i think we both did for future searchers of this issue.